# How can i make the generate numbers button work?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I'm working on a code that is to generate random numbers from 0 to whatever number a user entered as input

this is the js code but it doesn't work. please help me identify the problem i've checked for days now

```
const button = document.querySelector("button");


button.addEventListener("click", () =\> {
const num = document.querySelector("#number").textContent;
const userNum = parseInt(num, 10);

for (let i = 0; i \<= num; i++) {
let container = document.createElement("div");
container.textContent = i;
// function to check if a number is a prime number
function isPrime(number) {
if (number \<= 1) return false;
if (number \<= 3) return true;

if (number % 2 === 0 || number % 3 === 0) return false;

for (let i = 5; i \* i \<= number; i += 6) {
if (number % i === 0 || number % (i + 2) === 0) return false;
}

return true;
}

if (isPrime(i)) {
container.style.backgroundColor = "red";
} else if (i % 2 === 0) {
container.style.backgroundColor = "green";
} else if (i % 2 !== 0) {
container.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
let containerElement = document.querySelector("#numberContainer");
containerElement.appendChild(container);
}
});
```

Comment: you'll find code easier to debug if you indent - also, `=\>` is invalid - you probably have an error in your console - in fact, you have many \ in your code that don't belong - also `it doesn't work` isn't a useful problem statement. What SHOULD it do? What DOES it do instead?

Comment: thank you...i'm sure all the \ are a mistake...they're not in the original code

Comment: We are not to know that!!! Anyway, do you get any errors in the browser console? What should this code do? What does it do? saying "it doesn't work" doesn't actually mean anything, if it worked, you wouldn't be asking a question :p